# Detrending and data transformation to logarithm can be done together?

Tags: econometrics, data-transformation, regression-coefficients, trend, logarithm

I want to get the effect of bitcoin price changes on foreign currency price. The third variable is inflation, which is an explanatory variable.
Should variables be detrended before regressing? Is it necessary to convert variables into logarithms after detrending?

What should be done if by entering a new variable in the model, the first variable becomes meaningless and its sign changes?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the effect of bitcoin price changes on foreign currency price.

Worth reconsidering: You propose that the predictor is the change in a price of X whereas the response is price of Y. Usually we use price to predict price and changes in price to predict changes in price.

> The third variable is inflation, which is an explanatory variable.

Also worth reconsidering: Inflation is usually incorporated by normalizing all price variables from nominal to real values using a simple formula `price/CPI`. When used as a separate predictor, it means the price of everything else. See https://otexts.com/fpp3/transformations.html

> Should variables be detrended before regressing?

What you call as detrending is also referred to as differencing. Whether differencing is needed depends on the stationarity (integration) of the residual series (if it follows a fixed normal distribution without temporal correlation). There are tests for it. If the error term is stationary (Y and X are cointegrated), no further differencing is needed. See https://otexts.com/fpp3/arima.html

> Is it necessary to convert variables into logarithms after detrending?

Differencing is a type of conversion. If conversion makes the error term to have nice properties while differencing is still needed, we convert variables before differencing. A differenced variable will have both positive and negative values, making logarithm and transformations difficult. For price series, we usually take a first-order difference in `log(price)`, as $\ln p_{t = 2} - \ln p_{t = 1}$.

> What should be done if by entering a new variable in the model, the first variable becomes meaningless and its sign changes?

This means at least one of the two model specifications is incorrect and vulnerable. It does not necessarily means that the other specification is correct. In you context, the plausible case is that in `foreign ~ bitcoin` the slope is positive, whereas in `foreign ~ bitcoin + cpi` the slope of bitcoin is negative. Both of these two models are unreasonable because there are many other variables much more important than the bitcoin price that affect foreign currency prices.  For causal inference in times series and macroeconomics, see Bauer, M. D., & Swanson, E. T. (2023). An alternative explanation for the “Fed Information Effect.” American Economic Review, 113(3), 664–700. https://doi.org/10.1257/aer.20201220.